# Animating line selector in flatlist react native

Tags: react-native, animation

I have a vertical flatlist of items with a selected state.
The state include a vertical line to highlight selection.

I want to add an animated selector line such that when I select another item, the line animates to the selected item.
The behaviour is as seen in blinkit and instamart app as well.

Here are the two approached I've tried:

1. I have tried including selector in `renderItem` and then animating it. The problem is that on each selection the y position of selector changes which does not give a consistent animation.
2. I tried keeping an `Animated.View` out of flatlist but it has two issues, a) had to scroll the selector with flatlist by using `onScroll` prop. b) When selecting another item not able to calculate the desired offset since selection line view is constrained to window height and does not take flatlist y position.

How do we implement such feature in react native?